# OpenCV path error in cmake

Tags: 16.04, environment-variables, cmake, opencv

Every time when I try to build and install any library which depends on OpenCV, The cmake of that library throws the following error,

```
-- OpenCV ARCH: 

-- OpenCV RUNTIME: 

-- OpenCV STATIC: OFF

CMake Warning at /home/wizviz/opencv-2.4.9/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake:161 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/wizviz/opencv-2.4.9/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/wizviz/dataset-tools-master/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Is it about adding OpenCV to Ubuntu 16.04 environment.? 
How do I solve it?